# Change how acronyms appears in text

Tags: acronyms, acro

How can I automatically print acronyms in text, using `\ac{OFDM}` command, as follows?

The waveform OFDM (*Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing*) is a multi-carrier....

Currently `\ac{OFDM}` command results in:

The waveform *Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing* (OFDM) is a multi-carrier....

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{makeidx}


\DeclareAcronym{OFDM}{
    short = OFDM,
    long = orthogonal frequency division multiplexing,
    list = \noindent\emph{Orthogonal frequency division multiplexing},
    first-long-format = \itshape,
    class = Ac,
}


\begin{document}

The waveform \ac{OFDM} is a multi-carrier....

\end{document}
```

**The code results in:**

[image]

Please, I need some help with this

Comment: what's the `\noindent` there for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\acsetup{first-style=reversed}` to your preamble.

Comment: Could you add some details on how this solves the problem? Perhaps add an example?

Comment: Thank you, it worked!